# Packing an upwards equilateral triangle efficiently by downwards equilateral triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering, triangles

Consider the problem of packing an upwards-pointing unit equilateral triangle "efficiently" by downwards-pointing equilateral triangles, where "efficiently" means that  there is little wasted area relative to the perimeter of the triangles used in the packing.  The $n^{th}$ generation of the Sierpinski triangle

[image: Sierpinski triangle from Wikipedia]

packs all but $(3/4)^n$ of the area of the large upwards triangle by downwards triangles, at the cost of a net perimeter of $\asymp (3/2)^n$.  Thus, if we let $\varepsilon$ denote the area not packed, then the perimeter of the triangles used in this construction is $\gg \varepsilon^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha = \frac{\log (3/2)}{\log (4/3)} = 1.409\dots$.

My question is whether this phenomenon is general: given any finite collection of downward equilateral triangles in the upward unit equilateral triangle that is a packing (i.e., interiors are disjoint) and leaves an area of $\varepsilon$ not covered, is it true that the total perimeter of the triangles used is of the form $\gg \varepsilon^{-c}$ for some absolute constant $c>0$? For my application I do not need an optimal exponent $c$. [EDIT: as pointed out in answers, to make the answer positive for large $\varepsilon$, the outer triangle should also count towards the total perimeter.]

I think I can establish a bound of the form $\gg \log \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ (roughly speaking, by arguing that every dyadic scale of triangles between $\varepsilon$ and $1$ has to contribute a constant amount of perimeter, otherwise there will be too much waste), but for my application I really need a polynomial lower bound (or maybe $\exp( (\log\log \frac{1}{\varepsilon})^C )$ for a large absolute constant $C$ might suffice). It's intuitively plausible to me that the Sierpinski packing is the "best" packing for this purpose, and that the smaller triangles really have to contribute more than a constant amount of perimeter, but I am finding it surprisingly tricky to locate a rigorous argument.  Perhaps this sort of question has already been studied in the literature?

One can interpret this question as an exotic form of an isoperimetric inequality, where the region of interest is required to be a disjoint union of downwards pointing equilateral triangles in a fixed upward pointing triangle, but this question seems rather orthogonal to the usual theory of isoperimetric inequalities, so I don't believe that this interpretation is particularly fruitful.

Comment: The trivial lower bound is $e^{c\sqrt{\log 1/\varepsilon}}$. Will that be sufficient?

Comment: That should suffice I think.

Answer (score 17):

OK, posting then.

I prefer to think of triangles pointing to the right in the triangle pointing to the left. Let $\delta=e^{-\sqrt{\log 1/\varepsilon}}$. For each small triangle $T$, let $I$ be the interval of length $\delta$ times the length of the projection of $T$ to the horizontal axis with the same endpoint. If the sum of lengths of $I$'s is noticeable, we are done.

Otherwise, for each $x$ not in the union of $I$'s, the intersections of the triangles with the corresponding vertical line form a system of intervals $J$ satisfying $\operatorname{dist}(J',J'')\ge \delta\min(|J'|,|J''|)$ and for many $x$ those intervals cover the cross-section up to $\varepsilon$ or so.

Now assume that we have $K=K(x)$ intervals in this system. All gaps are at most $\varepsilon$. Take every fifth gap and remove the adjacent interval of length $\le\varepsilon/\delta$. We'll remove a fixed portion of the intervals and the gaps will become $\le\varepsilon/\delta$ (well, $+2\varepsilon$, of course, but who cares?). Repeat for $\frac 12\sqrt{\log 1/\varepsilon}$ steps. Either we will be still left with something, in which case we have $K\ge e^{c\sqrt{\log 1/\varepsilon}}$ (at each step we remove a fixed portion of all remaining intervals), or we'll eliminate everything using only intervals of length $\sqrt\varepsilon$ or less, which results in $K\ge\varepsilon^{-1/2}$, which is even better (our intervals have to almost cover the cross-section). But then the total perimeter is at least $\int K(x)\,dx$ over the good set and we are done again.

There may be some room for improvement here, but that would require some more thinking :-)

Comment: Thanks!  For my application, it is actually the lower bound on $\sup_x K(x)$ which is important, rather than the perimeter, and your argument actually gives a polynomial bound in that case, so I have all that I need for my application, thanks!  The general case (where one seeks a polynomial lower bound on the perimeter) still seems intellectually interesting, though.

Comment: For $\sup_x K(x)$, couldn't you look at the set of points in the right-most $(100\epsilon)$-fraction of our big triangle? At most 10 percent (say) of these points are uncovered. So by averaging, there is some $x$ in this very-right region with at least 90 percent of points in the vertical slice covered.

However, every right-pointing triangle contributes intervals of length at most $O(\epsilon)$ inside this region. So we need $\Omega(1/\epsilon)$ intervals.

Comment: One can also make this little trick work 'away from the boundary'. The idea is that if we do not have polynomially large perimeter, we must have some large triangle $T^*$ with side-length $>\epsilon^c$ (for some small choice of $c>0$). But then, if we flip $T^*$ triangle along its vertical base, we can look at the $(100 \epsilon^{1-c})$-fraction of right-most points in this flipped area. And the trick works here too, which allows you to find values of $x$ away from the right-most boundary of the host triangle (since $T^*$ should appear in lots of places).